# Force my viewcontroller to landscape when the viewcontroller loads

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation

I want to open my view controller with landscape mode and block portrait  even when the device is in potrait orientation .i have 4 viewcontroller where the first three  have all the orientations present and the last viewcontroller should have only landscape mode and block potrait mode while presenting the screen .Is that possible ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What versions of iOS do you need to support?

Comment: i wanted it to work in ios 5 and above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is possible you can write this code where you wanted to landscape mode..

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape

}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interface
{
    return (interface==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape)

}
```

Comment: No ,it is not working .Actually i am pushing it from a potrait viewcontroller and the above code when i use shows me in potrait only

Comment: @ArunMak, where did you add the code shown and what version of iOS are you testing (iOS 5 and iOS 6 require different code...)

Comment: i am testing for both ios 5 and ios6 .That is it should work in both ios5 and iOS 6 .I have added the above code in the last viewcontroller where i wanted it to appear in landscape

Comment: are you getting the solution..

Comment: if this code help you then mark as a accepted...

Comment: No i am not getting the solution

Answer (score 0):

write below code in AppDelegate

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

}
```

Comment: No still the view controller opens in potrait view only

Comment: @ArunMak please explain ...start on app view is potrait then what want  to do ?

Comment: i have 4 view controllers  where the first three allows potrait as well as landscape mode and when pushed from the third viewcontroller i want the fourth view controller to open only in landscape and block portrait mode

Comment: @ArunMak check this pastie http://pastie.org/8232401
any other issue plz tell me .

Comment: you are right but the first time when it moves to fourth view controller it is still in potrait once i rotate it gets fixed to landscape

Comment: @ArunMak buddy you can set your conditions please check it ...